# Image becomes larger after link (a href tag) is removed even though height is defined

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, image-resizing

I had some image links previously, where all the images had a defined height. After I removed the links (a href tags), the images became larger.

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePsxC.png

I want it to look like the 1st row, where they're all the same size (versus the 2nd row where the circles are larger because I removed the links), but I don't want the circles to be linked to anything. I have also defined margins and borders, so I don't think it's a default browser issue. It probably has something to do with my nested divs holding the image links, but I don't know what.

Thanks so much for any help you can offer.

Here is the website if it helps to view the source: http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/aboutus/example.cfm

Relevant CSS:

```
.text2col{
margin-left:12.5em;
border:0.1em solid black;
background-color:white;
padding:1em;
min-width:46em;
overflow:auto;
text-align:left;
max-height:31em;

}

.text2colin{
overflow:auto;
}

.teaminfo{
margin-left:5em;
margin-top:-0.25em;
}

#img{
text-align:center;
}

.imgteam{
margin:1em;
height:auto;
width:auto;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}

.imgteam a:hover img{
border:0.2em solid #cd05ff;
}

.imgteam img{
display:inline;
margin:0;
border:0.2em solid black;
width:9.5em;
height:9.5em;
-moz-border-radius:4.75em;
-webkit-border-radius:4.75em;
border-radius:4.75em;
}

.imgschool{
margin:1em;
height:auto;
width:auto;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}

.imgschool a:hover img{
border:0.2em solid #cd05ff;
}

.imgschool img{
display:inline;
margin:0;
border:0.2em solid black;
width:19em;
height:9.5em;
-moz-border-radius:2em;
-webkit-border-radius:2em;
border-radius:2em;
}

.teamcaption{
text-align:center;
font-weight:normal;
width:auto;
margin:0.2em;
}

.imgteamsmall img{
width:4em;
height:4em;
-moz-border-radius:1em;
-webkit-border-radius:1em;
border-radius:1em;
border:0.2em solid black;
float:left;
}
```

Relevant html:

```
<div class="text2colin">

<div class="imgschool"><a target="blank" href="http://terc.edu"><img src="img/school.png" alt="picture of school"></a>
<div class="teamcaption"><p class="img"><strong>Name of school</strong><br />School system</p>
    </div>
</div>              

<div class="imgteam"><a href="#teacherinfo"><img src="img/school.png" alt="picture of teacher"></a>
<div class="teamcaption"><p class="img"><strong>Teacher's name</strong><br />Grade # Teacher</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imgteam"><a href="teacherinfo"><img src="img/school.png" alt="picture of teacher"></a>
<div class="teamcaption"><p class="img"><strong>Teacher's name</strong><br />Grade # Teacher</p>
    </div>
</div>                

</div><!--end div class=text2colin-->

<div class="text2colin">

<h4>Section Header Two</h4>

</div><!--end div class=text2colin-->

<div class="text2colin">

<div class="imgschool"><a target="blank" href="http://terc.edu"><img src="img/school.png" alt="picture of school"></a>
<div class="teamcaption"><p class="img"><strong>Name of school</strong><br />School system</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imgteam"><img src="img/school.png" alt="picture of teacher">
<div class="teamcaption"><p class="img"><strong>Teacher's name</strong><br />Grade # Teacher</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imgteam"><img src="img/school.png" alt="picture of teacher">
<div class="teamcaption"><p class="img"><strong>Teacher's name</strong><br />Grade # Teacher</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't happen when I try here, so do you have more styles somewhere, that could change the font size of `a` elements?

Comment: @MrLister, thanks for looking. I forgot to put up the test site; I've edited the URL now. No, I haven't defined an a element anywhere else--actually, I didn't know that I could, which is why I defined the styles for the img.

Answer (score 1):

Try using px instead of em. Example : `height: 100px`.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the piece of CSS you posted here, but in your `fonts.css` stylesheet, where you have

```
a:link {text-decoration:none; color:blue; font-size:0.9em}
```

And as font sizes are inherited, everything in the `a` will have this font size, and `9.5em` in the `a` will not be the same as `9.5em` outside of it!